# Standardize features to calculate variance inflation factors

Tags: python, statsmodels, sklearn-pandas, standardized

I'm calculating variance inflation factors

```
from patsy import dmatrices
from statsmodels.stats.outliers_influence import variance_inflation_factor
y, X = dmatrices('A ~ B + C + D + E + F + G, data=df, return_type='dataframe')

vif = pd.DataFrame()
vif['VIF'] = [variance_inflation_factor(X.values, i) for i in range(X.shape[1])]
vif['variable'] = X.columns
vif
```

How can I now standardize the features using StandardScaler() and then re-calculate the variance inflation factors of the standardized features?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using "patsy import dmatrices" already scales and standardizes the features. Therefore there is no need to do a second step with StandardScaler()

Answer (score 0):

Check out patsy's [stateful transforms](https://patsy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/stateful-transforms.html) and [standardize](https://patsy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/API-reference.html#patsy.standardize).